# Scala: Partial function error: use _ if you want to treat it as a PartialFunction

Tags: scala, lift-json, partialfunction

The following piece of code does not work:
FileSystems.getDefault.getPath is from the java.nio package

Update:

Method createCalculation is:

Note: MyLocation is a case class that extends MyMessage

```
def creatCalculation(myPlace: MyLocation): MyMessage = {
    if (some test) {
       //--- some code
    } else
       MyError("My Calculation already done")

        MyAck //returning the case object MyAck which is of type MyMessage
  }
```

//Req is the class from: net.liftweb.http.Req

```
val someVal: PartialFunction[Req, () => Box[LiftResponse]] {

case "create" :: Nil JsonPostAndApproval s =>
          postResponse(s, (j: JValue, p: Permissions, r: Req) => {
        createCalculation(fromJValue[MyLocation](j) = {
          case "MyAck" => {
             val myCalculator: Calculator = new Calculator(FileSystems.getDefault.getPath(fromJsonVal[MyLocation](s._1).path))
             val resultsMap = myCalculator.foreach( (p) => Map[String,  Int])
                 for( (myKey, myValue) <- resultsMap) {
                    printf("key: %s, value:  %s\n", myKey, myValue)
                 }
          }
        })
      } ) ("Failed to calculate")

 }
```

The compiler complains like this:

```
[error] C:\Users\lulu\ExampleHandler.scala:129: missing arguments for
method fromJValue in package json;
[error] follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
[error]         createCalculation(fromJsonVal[MyLocation](j) = {
[error]                                  ^
```

This is the method definition for fromJsonVal

```
/**
   * Routine to convert JValue to native type
   *
   * @param in JValue to convert
   * @tparam T native type to extract
   * @return extracted native type
   */
  def fromJsonVal[T: Manifest](in: JValue): T = in.extract[T]
```

JValue is from net.liftweb/json and is:
sealed abstract class JValue()extends java.lang.Object with net.liftweb.json.Diff.Diffable  {
   <>
}

Update: the compiler is reporting an error is in this line of code

How do you think I should correct this compile error?

```
   createCalculation(fromJValue[MyLocation](j) = {
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the full picture, I think the error is merely from you trying to assign an output to a method AND a missing parens. Without the full picture, my guess would be that you are looking for something more like:

```
createCalculation(fromJValue[MyLocation](j)) match {
  case "MyAck"....
```

Note the double paren after `j`

Comment: I will add more context to the question

Comment: I have added more detail to the code. The case is contained with a val that is a PartialFunction

Comment: Your correction did not help: The error I am now getting is: "type mismatch: expected: MyLocation, actual: Unit

Comment: @user3825558 well, that is because createCalculation is getting passed the output of the match. With this new info, it looks like you are missing a parentheses after the j so that it passes the MyLocation to createCalculations and then you can match against the output of that

Comment: It still does not work: It now complains like this:                                                       Type mismatch:, expected (JsonAST.JValue, Permissions, Req) => MyMessage                                                                                                       Actual: (JsonAST.JValue, Permissions, Req) => Unit

Comment: Again, because the final value is the return value, which is a foreach....which returns a Unit. Sounds like you can remove the match altogether and return the result of the createCalculation. However, you will still have the dangling odd function...which seems like you should just get rid of the = {. Is that case really just another case of the partial function?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I am going to try out your suggestion again.

Comment: No, I want that case is about returning a Map[String, Int]

Comment: You realize you aren't returning it. The last piece of execution is a for loop, which returns Unit. You need to return the resultsMap after the for loop....which the resultsMap is actually a Unit, you want a map, not a foreach...